# Where does the extra matter come from to a relativistic particle?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, inertial-frames, mass-energy

Mass by definition is the amount of matter contained in a body. But for a relativistic object its relativistic mass is greater than the actual rest mass. If accelerating a body increases its mass then by definition it is increasing the amount of matter in a body.

So my question is where does this extra matter come from?

Comment: No, that is not the way to look at it any more.....https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/mass-energy-matter-etc/more-on-mass/the-two-definitions-of-mass-and-why-i-use-only-one/     is a very good article. Well worth a read.

Comment: Closely related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/50583

Comment: The amount of matter does not increase.  The resistance to having it's state of motion change increases.    One way of looking at it is to say that the particle's mass increases, but that point of view leads to problems in interpretation, as you have discovered.  Physicists abandoned that point of view at least half a century ago.      Einstein warned against  it.   For unknown reasons, the idea that mass increases persists.  In the current interpretation, mass is constant.

Comment: @garyp. Because they still teach it that way, in my  neck of the woods anyway. Also, TV documentaries  love the drama aspect of it.

Answer (score 0):

'Perceived mass' is just another name for energy, and the contribution to that from kinetic energy specifically depends on relative motion of body and observer.